# Azure Disks-Adding disk without stopping it

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, azure-networking

Can anyone help me to know if we can add disk to azure vm without shutting it down or stopping the VM?

Comment: we can via azure portal to add azure disk, there is no need to stop this VM

Comment: which size of your azure vm? how many disks have you add?

Comment: okay I can add the disk, if any changes I want to make, for example I want to increase the size by 2 gb, I will have to shut down or stop

Comment: For now, a data disk up to 1023G.

Comment: Add a data disk will not reboot this VM.

Comment: I got your point. I have added the disk(500gb), now I want to edit it and increase the size to 550GB without stoping the Vm.

Comment: Disks can be resized only when they're unattached or the owner VM is deallocated. If this is a data disk, we can dis-attach this disk, and use PowerShell to resize it, in this way, we can don't to stop this VM.

Comment: Deallocating Vm is nothing but stopping it. So I still have to stop the VM to resize the data disk.

Comment: we have two chose, deallocate this vm or unattach this VM's disk.

Answer (score 1):

As we know, we can attach a data disk to Azure VM and there is **no** need to stop this VM.
Here a official article about attach a data disk to Azure Windows VM, please refer to [it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/attach-disk).

By the way, if you reached the limit of number of disks, we should resize the VM, and this need a reboot.

=========
**Update**:
Sorry for my mistake, in Azure ASM module we can resize data disk without shutdown VM, but in ARM, we should shutdown this VM and update data disk with powershell, here is the powershell script:

```
$vm = get-azurermvm -resourcegroup vms -name jasonv
$vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks
Set-AzureRmVMDataDisk -VM $vm -Name jasonv-20170531-143430 -DiskSizeInGB 20
update-azurermvm -vm $vm -ResourceGroupName vms
```

Comment: you can refer to the link in my answer.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: If it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks :)

Comment: I have added the disk from Vm, went to disk and clicked on add a disk. Now to resize it how do I un attach it?

Comment: @alokJahagirdar we can via Azure portal to do it, i have add it to the answer, please check it.

Comment: @alokJahagirdar please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Jason : as per your screenshot, when you click on that icon to detach and then save it, attached disk is no more visible.

Comment: Jason: the link you gave says that VM needs to be shuitdown to de allocate and then resize the data disk.

Comment: @alokJahagirdar we can use powershell to list this disk, also we can via azure portal to add an existing data disk.

Comment: @alokJahagirdar sorry for my mistake, in Azure ASM module, we can resize Azure vm data disk without reboot this VM, but in ARM module, we have to shutdown this VM, I have update my answer, I apologize for the inconvenience.